# apache basic authentication - how to disable on dev computer

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I'm disabling access to some folders to unauthorized users this way:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access to private admin section"
Require valid-user
```

It works fine on the production (Ubuntu) server.
The problem is I want the same code to allow access (or at least ask for password) on a windows dev computer.

Tried adding

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But the logs show error because it cannot find the password file on the dev computer.
The system cannot find the path specified.  : Could not open password file: C:/var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private

Whats the elegant way to tell apache to either allow access or ask for password on the dev computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the directory `C:/var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private` and then use the `htpasswd.exe` program that comes with your apache installation to create the `.htpasswd_private` file

```
htpasswd -c C:/var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private username
Automatically using MD5 Format
New password: *********
Re-type password: *********
Adding password for user username
```

Now you should have a system works like your production server.

Comment: btw, copying the password files from the production server also works.
This is not the elegant solution I wanted (wanted to avoid creating this c:/var folder) but it works.

Comment: I know you can copy the file from the production system but I don't know your companies security policy regarding that so I went back to basics. To me as a sysadmin this is elegant as it makes your development system just like (or very similar to) your production system and reduces the work required to put your changes into production.

Answer (score 1):

Allow from does not mean you can just login without password, it just sets what hosts can access it. It will still ask you for a password.

You have two options :

1. Create a valid .htpasswd_private file in `C:/var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private`
2. You delete these options in your directory declaration :

   AuthUserFile /var/www/passwords/.htpasswd_private

   AuthType Basic

   AuthName "Access to private admin section"

   Require valid-user

And you just leave the Allow from 127.0.0.1 statement.

Answer (score 0):

I had a dual htpasswd+LDAP authentication `AuthBasicProvider file ldap` as follow:
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MyApp"

```
AuthBasicProvider file ldap

AuthUserFile /var/www/domain.tld/myapp/.htpasswd

# LDAP
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.domain.tld:636/dc=domain,dc=tld?uid?sub?(&(objectClass=person)(mail=*@domain.tld))" SSL
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=myapp,OU=Applications,DC=domain,DC=tld"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxxxxxxx"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

Require valid-user
```

Removing/commenting only the following directives seems to be enough:

- `AuthUserFile`
- `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative`
- `Require`